# I want to fill 2 tables in database in one ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a IActionResult fucntion and I can fill a table in it but I want to fill 2 in the same one

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(User model)
        {

            if (!IsValidation(model))
            {
                TempData["error"] += "Please fill the empty places. ";
                return View(model);
            }
            if (_userService.CheckEmail(model.Email))
            {
                TempData["error"] += "This e-mail is already being used ";
                return View(model);
            }

            model.RolId = _rolService.Get(x => x.Name == "User").First().Id;

            _userService.Add(model);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

I have 2 tables, User and Profile.

When I can only do it for one table

Basicly I want to do something like this

```
public IActionResult Index(User model, Profile model)
```

But it says, Ambiguity between 'User' and 'ProfileOptions

Is it possible to do it in one view?

Comment: Why not create a new model that wraps User and Profile models?

Comment: I know but I want to do it in that way

Comment: "But it says, Ambiguity between 'User' and 'ProfileOptions'" Can you explain this some more please? Could you generate a profile object from a user object?

Comment: Maybe you need a write a custom binder for this. I dont see a reason to have two binding arguments, Its more like using x-www-form-urlencoded, where the value could be  different jsons coverted to strings.

Comment: Does your view have partial views with User and Profile models?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this way?
Create a `dto` that contains `User` and `Profile`:

```
public class UserProfileDto
{
   public User user {get;set;} 
   public Profile profile {get;set;
}
```

And change your action as follows:

```
public IActionResult Index(UserProfileDto dto){}
```

After that, you can retrieve `User` and `Profile` from dto.

Comment: but also I want to use my repository design patter with services I was using them with model.Table name is it still possible?

Comment: Yes, you can create different repositories for `User` and `Profile` and create a service to handle `User` and `Profile` to prevent implementing business in your controller.
I can explain more if it doesn't make sense.